# Elasticsearch docker container: max virtual memory error

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch

I've pulled the Elasticsearch docker image and ran it according to the instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html).

However, the processes exits due to the following error:

```
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

- Isn't a docker container supposed to ready to run, without issues?
- [This site](https://opster.com/analysis/error-1-bootstrap-checks-failed/) suggests `sysctl vm.max_map_count 262144`. Is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve Max virtual memory low error you need to use the below command :

> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

But this setting will reset to its original value, after the host reboots. To make this change permanent you need to add `vm.max_map_count` to `262144` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: MAny thanks for the help... Here's a problem... Due to this error, whenever I try to run the image, or restart the exited container, the container  exits almost immediately due to the error. So, I've tried `docker start es01 && docker exec -ti es01 sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`
However, I get: `es01
sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count", ignoring: Read-only file system
`

Comment: Do you know how I'm able to solve this?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. no, please update